# how to represtnt sqlite query in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to represnet this sql query in Sqlite in android ?

```
select id,name,topic from books where id=1 and topic ="art"
```

Answer (score 3):

run a query on your `SQLiteDatabase` object and save it in a `Cursor`:

`Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("select id,name,topic from books where id = ? and topic = ?", new String[] {"1", "art"});`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cursor as you can see in my example:

```
protected SQLiteDatabase dataDB;

//Get DB
Context context = getBaseContext();  
LocationBookSQLite dbHelper = new LocationBookSQLite(context);  
dataDB = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 

//use a cursor to get db elements
Cursor cur = dataDB.query(books, 
                null, null, null, null, null, null);
cur.moveToFirst();
while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
  if ( cur.getString(1).equals(1) && cur.getString(3).equals("art")) {
    //here 1 mean the index of id
    System.out.println(cur.getString(1));
    //here 2 mean the index of name
    System.out.println(cur.getString(2));
    //here 3 mean the index of topic
    System.out.println(cur.getString(3));
  }
cur.moveToNext();
}
cur.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Class which handle all query execution like this

```
public Cursor getData(Context context, DBHelper dbHelper, String columnName, 
String tableName, String where) {
    query = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + tableName + " " + where;
    cursor = dmsUtility.rawQueryDataAttach(context, dbHelper, query);
    return cursor;
}
public boolean insertData(Context context, DBHelper dbHelper, String 
 columnName,String valueData, String tableName, String where) {
    query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " " + columnName + " VALUES (" 
           + valueData + " )" + where;
    dmsUtility.execSQLAttach(context, dbHelper, query);
    return true;
}
public boolean updateData(Context context, DBHelper dbHelper, String 
           columnName, String tableName, String where) {
    query = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + columnName + " " + where;
    dmsUtility.execSQLAttach(context, dbHelper, query);
    return true;
}
```

And call function

```
DMSConstant.COLUMNNAME = "select id,name,topic";
DMSConstant.TABLENAME = "from books";
DMSConstant.WHERE = "where id=1 and topic ="art" ";

Cursor cursorBody = dbHelper.getData(getContext(), dbHelper, 
DMSConstant.COLUMNNAME, DMSConstant.TABLENAME, DMSConstant.WHERE);
```